# Javascript "classes" withouth "new" keyword

Tags: javascript

I understand that in Javascript classes don't really exist.
An that in reality you're just making a function to construct an object for you.

Not so long ago (before syntactic sugar like "class" was introduced) the only way to mimic a class (and arguably still the best) was as follows :

```
function Car () {

this.type = "fancy";
this.color = "red";
}

Car.prototype.getInfo = function() {

return this.color + " " + this.type + " car";
};

let car = new Car();
```

I was wondering how this would look like without "new".
**Does the following piece of code do exactly the same as the first piece of code?**

```
function Car(self) {

self.type = "fancy";
self.color = "red";
}

Car.prototype.getInfo = function() {

return this.color + " " + this.type + " car";
};

let car = {};
Car(car);
car.__proto__ = Car.prototype;
```

Comment: a) you'd use `Object.setPrototypeOf` instead of the deprecated `__proto__` b) you'd set it on the new object *before* calling the constructor c) you'd `call` the constructor so that its `this` keyword refers to the new object, with `Car.call(car)`

Comment: Thanks this is where is was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe they're equivalent. However, you can avoid having to repeat all 3 steps when creating the object by putting those steps in the `Car` function itself:

```js
function Car() {
  let instance = {}
  instance.type = "fancy";
  instance.color = "red";
  instance.__proto__ = Car.prototype;
  return instance;
}
Car.prototype.getInfo = function() {
  return this.color + " " + this.type + " car";
};

let car = Car();
console.log(car.getInfo());
```

You can read a summary of what `new` does in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description).

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, `car.__proto__.constructor.length == 0`.  In the second example, it has a value of `1`.  So depending on how literal you want to be, they may not be equivalent.

> I understand that in Javascript classes don't really exist.
>
> syntactic sugar like "class"

Classes are syntactic sugar in every language that supports them.  A JavaScript class isn't any less "real" than a C++ class.  If anything, it's more real, since it isn't permanently abstracted away to machine code.

Comment: Well, I think calling classes "syntactic sugar" in JS makes more sense, cause you can reason about the behaviour of classes if you know how functions and prototypes work. Classes in e.g. C++ introduce "new things" (e.g. destructors) that you cannot replace with other fundamental structures.